# How should "git add /**" work?

Tags: git

As noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378172/where-do-you-report-bugs-in-git#comment13379812_10378172), I ran into an issue with `git add /**...`. I can't actually find any documentation on the "/**" form of path specifications - possibly because it's hard to google.

How is it meant to work, exactly? I'm particularly curious that `git add /\*\*.py` can work but `git add /path/foo.py` won't - why is the slash allowed at the start of the string with the ** notation?

EDIT more info:

```
$ echo /**.py
/**.py
```

(This version of Bash doesn't support `shopt -s globstar`)

Yet:

```
$ git add /**.py
```

adds (silently) a file three directories beneath the current directory. Git apparently doesn't do any globbing at all, so I'm really curious what's going on here.

These also work:

```
`git add '/**.py'`
`git add /*******.py`
```

This doesn't:

```
`git add **.py`
```

This seems to add all files anywhere in the current working directory.

(Bash 3.2.48 on OSX)

Comment: You need to define "work" here - Please paste the actual commands, the output, and what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: Ok, I pasted the commands above. None of them produce any output. I don't have "what I expected to happen" - that's what I'm asking. The behaviour where it adds no files, and produces no output seems confusing, so I'm asking how these commands are being interpreted.

Answer (score 6):

Globs are resolved by the shell when you run such a command, not by `git`. Try `echo /**` to see what that resolves to. There is a recursive glob pattern in Bash which uses this syntax, but you have to `shopt -s globstar` to enable it (it seems to be disabled by default).

`git add /\*\*.py` tries to add a file called *literally* `**.py`. While it's possible to create such a file, it's probably not intended.

`git /path/foo.py` is meaningless - I assume you meant `git add /path/foo.py`.

In all these commands, you should remove the initial slash - You generally want to refer to files in a repository by their path *relative* to `$PWD`.

`echo /**.py` will print `/**.py` *unless* `shopt nullglob` is `off` *or* you actually have a `.py` file in the root directory.